# Series of supremums

Tags: real-analysis

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $A_n$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^+\cup\{0\}$ and $L\ge 0$ a fixed real number with the following property:

If $a_n\in A_n$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\le L$.

Is it true that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sup A_n\le L$? Any hint to prove it if it is true?

Thanks :)

Comment: Write the inequality for a finite sum, then take the sup, then take the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Try by contradiction. If $S=\sum\sup A_n>L$, then there must be a finite number, say $N$, so $S_N>L$, where $S_N$ denotes the partial sum. Since by definition, the supremum is the least upper bound, you can find an element $a_n\in A_n$ so that $\sup(A_n)-a_n<\varepsilon/2N$ where $0<\varepsilon<S_N-L$. Then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\geq\sum_{n=1}^N a_n>\sum_{n=1}^N(\sup(A_n)-\varepsilon/2N)=\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\sup(A_n)\right)-\varepsilon/2>L+\varepsilon/2. $$This contradicts the hypothesis, so we are done.

Note that we don't need to concern ourselves with any cancellation because we are working with nonnegative real numbers.